# Small, simple examples of asynchronous transmission in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, asynchronous

I am trying to work on application in which images should be loaded asynchronously.

Are there any examples related this?

I tried pokeb-asi to understand asynchronous transmission, and it works within that application fine.

But I want to know how to do it from scratch

I am facing following problems.

- I don't know the exact way to do it?
- what kind of files / frameworks should be added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ASIHTTPRequest` class is a subclass of `NSOperation`, so it's typically used by adding the request to either an `NSOperationQueue` or an `ASINetworkQueue`. Each request is pulled off the queue, run in a background thread, and then the delegate for that request is notified via a callback method on the main thread.

You could wrap `NSURLConnection` in an `NSOperation` and achieve the same thing, however `NSURLConnection` has an asynchronous API which may suit your needs a bit better.

Comment: I think i needed the example. However your answer helped me a lot. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions